# How can I ask a user and read those files(s) into separate dataframes?

Tags: r

I have various data files in a folder. I want to create a format where I ask the user for a particular filename or names (Or I mention it in a particular list in the code) and the code reads those particular file(s) into separate dataframes. How can I do it?

```
01608500.dat
01608100.dat
01608520.dat
41608500.dat
```

I have been able to list the files using this:

```
files<-list.files(path="data",pattern="*.dat", full.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: How can I store it in separate dataframes? Right now, it gets stored in one big frame. Also, I would like the dataframe to have the same name as the file being read in...Though not absolutely necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the `files` in a `list` using `lapply` and then name the elements of `lst` with prefix of `files` using either `setNames` or `names`.  Then, you can use `list2env` to create individual `data.frame` objects (though, I wouldn't recommend it as you could do most of the analysis within the `list` environment itself)

```
lst <- lapply(files, read.table, header=TRUE) #comments from @Richard Scriven
names(lst) <- paste0('dat',sub('\\.dat', '', files))
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

#### Update

Using some files from my working directory

```
files <- list.files(pattern='.csv$', full.names=TRUE)
paste('dat',sub('\\.csv','', basename(files)),sep="_")[1:5]
#[1] "dat_01"             "dat_02"             "dat_12"            
#[4] "dat_a"              "dat_AuthorsRevised"
```

Comment: Yes, this is working! Thanks. However, the file names are adding some extra information like the filepath Anyway to only use the filename as given in the data?

Comment: Right now the filenames are being appended by this: datdata/

Comment: May be `paste0('dat',sub('\\.dat','', basename(pathtofilename\01608500.dat)))`

Comment: @maximusdooku  I am using prefix `dat` because it seems like your filenames start with `numbers`.  It may be better to have a data.frame object name that start with alphabets.

Comment: Ah, got it. thanks! It works now. Do you mind me asking - why is it better to have a letter instead of number at the beginning in R? I have never encountered it...